# Reference request: Skulls higher than the Himalayan mountains

Tags: reference-request, pali-canon, the-buddha, samsara

I’m looking for a sutta wherein the Buddha talks about the aimless wandering in Samsara and gives several analogies, one of them being about taking all the skulls one has left behind and piled them on top of each other and the pile would become taller than the Himalayan mountains.

I can for the life of me not find that anywhere. I know I read a while ago but now it can’t find it anywhere.

Does anyone know about this sutta?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sutta is [SN 15.10](https://www.dhammatalks.org/suttas/SN/SN15_10.html) (although it is unlikely the Buddha would engage in false speech like this, such as saying: "*Long have you thus experienced stress, experienced pain, experienced loss, swelling the cemeteries*".)

Comment: Thank you. It was heap of bones and mount Vepulla - not skulls or Himalayan mountains.

Comment: @Dhamma Dhatu, could it be that Buddha addressed the sentient beings at large, "long have you, [the countless generations of beings, ] have experienced dukkha, etc"?

Comment: Na, doesn't apply to me. I cannot recall long have I thus experienced stress, experienced pain, experienced loss, swelling the cemeteries.  Sure, life has its stresses, losses & pains but its not that "long" and cemeteries i have not noticed very much.